# PHP run a non blocking system call

Tags: php, parallel-processing, nonblocking

How can I run a non blocking system call in PHP?

The system call will call a streaming service run by a second PHP script.. So my page sits and waits on this call.

My two thoughts on a solution:

1: There exists a native method / parameter to execute a system call by non blocking

2: Run system() on a new C++ program that will then fork itself and run the actual php script, on a sep. thread

Is there a native method of executing system calls in a non blocking manner or do I need to hack around this...

I currently have shell_exec('nohup php /path/to/file.php &') but it still holds

Comment: Have you tried also piping stdout and stderr into files or /dev/null?  I would think that nohup would handle that, but worth a try.

Comment: Crontabs are probably what you're looking for. [Crontab PHP](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=crontab+php)

Comment: If i was looking for Crontabs I'd use them. Im running a spawn of background processes that streams tweets into data files, and have a consumer grab them and distribute them on my site. Not interested in relaying a bunch of pings w/ crontab, need open connection.

Comment: @Corbin, yes thanks buddy, ended up doing that and it let me move on :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

An example is provided in a comment on the same page (linux based):

> If you want to start a php process that continues to run independently
>   from apache (with a different parent pid) use nohub. Example:
>
> exec('nohup php process.php > process.out 2> process.err < /dev/null
>   &');

Comment: if i dont have a process.out... can i output it into /dev/null then?

Comment: That line means: put the output (stdout) of `nohup php process.php` in a file called `process.out`, its error stream (stderr) in another file called `process.err` and take the null stream /dev/null as input (stdin). You can find more details about I/O redirection in bash here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html.

Comment: Note that there is a typo in the quoted text - @all, make sure you use `nohup`, not `nohub`.